# which one should I use for this question 'faster or fast'

Tags: adverbs

I should walk **_______** so I can catch up with my brother.
Is the answer is fast or faster?

Comment: Either is fine. It depends what you want to mean.

Answer (score 1):

Either is valid. "Fast" is an absolute description of how you should walk. "Faster" implies a comparison to the current walking speed, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

**Faster** if you are already walking. ie. Your current walking speed isn't cutting it, you need to walk faster if you are going to catch up with him.

**Fast** if you're not currently walking. eg. Your brother left the house five minutes ago, you're going to need to walk fast if you want to catch up with him.